# Losing data via pyserial received from arduino via USB

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am using pyserial to access sensor data from the USB port via an arduino microcontroller. Unfortunately after one second of receiving data points, another second is missing, which is not acceptable for my application.
Meanwhile, the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE shows the data being sent continuously.
Can I fix this somehow in my Python Code?

```
import serial
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

### Reading the serial port

mylist = []

ArduinoLeonardoSerial = serial.Serial('com3',115200)
time.sleep(2)

timeout = 3                  # period for reading serial data
timeout_start = time.time()

while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
        line = ArduinoLeonardoSerial.readline().strip()
        values = line.decode('ascii').split(',')
        mylist.append(values)

ArduinoLeonardoSerial.close()


### Data processing

mylist.remove(mylist[0])
mylist.remove(mylist[-1])

accX = [x[0] for x in mylist]
accY = [x[1] for x in mylist]
accZ = [x[2] for x in mylist]
timestamp = [x[3] for x in mylist]

aX = np.asarray(accX, dtype=np.float32)
aY = np.asarray(accY, dtype=np.float32)
aZ = np.asarray(accZ, dtype=np.float32)
ts = np.asarray(timestamp, dtype=np.uint32)

start_timestamp = np.full((len(ts)), ts[0], dtype=np.uint32)
ts_normalized = ts - start_timestamp
```

The values for ts_normalized (in milliseconds) look like this:

```
    945  947  949  952  954  956  959  961  963  966  969  972  974  976 
    979  981  983  986  988 2101 2104 2106 2109 2111 2113 2116 2118 2121
```

So there's data cut off for about one second of measurement.

Answer (score 2):

remove the time.sleep(2). This ask for trouble because by not polling the information the interal buffer will overflow and the information will be lost.